# Styling CSS3 input fields inside JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

My current code is like that:

```
inp.style.marginTop="9px";
inp.style.width="150px";
inp.style.cursor="pointer";
inp.style.position="relative";
```

Now I'm trying to make it this way to make it look better on IE8, but it doesn't work - this should make input fields rounded:

```
inp.style.marginTop="9px";
inp.style.marginTop="7px\9";
inp.style.width="150px";
inp.style.cursor="pointer";
inp.style.behavior="url(/panel/css/pie/PIE.php)";
inp.style.position="relative";
inp.style.position="inline";
inp.style.display="block\9";
```

Answer (score 0):

User this for IE 8 browser issue

> http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/